# My arrayList won't transverse the list one by one and print everything?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a separate method `returnListOfBooks` in a class `BookShelf` which does the sorting by title in alphabetical order

```
private ArrayList<Book> listOfBooks;

    public BookShelf(ArrayList<Book> listOfBooks) {
        this.listOfBooks = listOfBooks;
    }

    public void addBook(Book a) {
        listOfBooks.add(a);
    }

public ArrayList<Book> returnListOfBooks() {
        for (int i = listOfBooks.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                //Is the two elements out of order?
                if (listOfBooks.get(j).getTitle().compareTo(
                        listOfBooks.get(j + 1).getTitle()) < 0) 
                {
                    //yes, then swap
                    Book temp = listOfBooks.get(j);
                    listOfBooks.set(j, listOfBooks.get(j + 1));
                    listOfBooks.set(j + 1, temp);

                } // end of inner for loop - arranging

            }
        }        
        for (int t = 0; t<listOfBooks.size(); t++)
        {
            System.out.print(listOfBooks.get(t) + " ");    
        }

        System.out.println();
        return listOfBooks;
    }
```

The user will have to input 20 books in the bookshelf and once there are already 20 books, I have to call this method in the main driver program and traverse the list of books and print them one by one sorting by title in alphabetical order. However, when I do so, **only the first book details in  the sorted list was printed out.**

here's how I called the method in the main driver program:

```
ArrayList<Book> listOfBooks = myBookshelf.returnListOfBooks();
        for (Book b: listOfBooks){
            System.out.println(b);
        }
```

anyone have an idea where did I go wrong? Hope you can help me out.

> Sample input:
>   Enter ID of the book: 23456
>
> Enter the author of the book: J.K Rowling
>
> Enter title of the book: Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
>
> Enter ID of the book: 56780
>
> Enter the author of the book: John Green
>
> Enter title of the book: The Fault in Our Starts
>
> Enter ID of the book: 45678
>
> Enter the author of the book: James Patterson
>
> Enter title of the book: Zoo
>
> ....
>
> (user will enter 20 times)
>
> Expected Output:
>
> ID: 23456, Author: J.K Rowling, Title: Harry Potter and the Goblet of
>   Fire
>
> ID: 56780, Author: John Green, Title: The Fault in Our Starts
>
> ID: 45678, Author: James Patterson, Title: Zoo
>
> ...
>
> (and so on, arranged by title in alphabetical order)

The output that I got:

```
Enter ID of the book: 23456

Enter the author of the book: J.K Rowling

Enter title of the book: Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire

Enter ID of the book: 56780

Enter the author of the book: John Green

Enter title of the book: The Fault in Our Starts

Enter ID of the book: 45678

Enter the author of the book: James Patterson

Enter title of the book: Zoo
```

....

(entered 20 times)

```
ID: 23456, Author: J.K Rowling, Title: Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

Comment: You don't show how `listOfBooks` is initialized (you didn't show that in the identical question you posted a few hours earlier either).

Comment: Looks like only one book ends up in the array. How do you read in the books? Do you use add()? Or set()?

Comment: Please add the system out of:

public ArrayList<Book> returnListOfBooks() {
        System.output.println(listOfBooks);

Comment: @Eran pardon. Added that in

Comment: @Arkadiy used `add()`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide all necessary code so I made my version. Maybe it will be helpful. Uncomment code to be able to input data from console, or just add more data to array.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.*;
class Book
{
    private int id;

    private String author;
    private String title;

    public Book() {}

    public Book(int id, String author, String title)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return this.title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ID: " + this.id + ", Author: " + this.author + ", Title: " + this.title;
    }
}

public class BookShelf
{
private List<Book> listOfBooks;

public BookShelf(List<Book> listOfBooks) {
    this.listOfBooks = listOfBooks;
}

public void addBook(Book a) {
    listOfBooks.add(a);
}

public List<Book> returnListOfBooks()
{
    Collections.sort(listOfBooks, this.cmp);
    return listOfBooks;
}

Comparator<Book> cmp = new Comparator<Book>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2)
    {
        int cmpresult = o1.getTitle().compareTo(o2.getTitle());
        return cmpresult;
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();

    /*
    Console con = System.console();
    if(con == null)
        System.exit(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        Book b = new Book();
        System.out.print("Enter ID of the book: ");
        b.setId(Integer.parseInt(con.readLine()));
        System.out.print("Enter the author of the book: ");
        b.setAuthor(con.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter title of the book: ");
        b.setTitle(con.readLine());
        list.add(b);

    }
    */
    list = Arrays.asList(new Book[]{new Book(45678, "James Patterson", "Zoo"),
            new Book(56780, "John Green", "The Fault in Our Starts"),
            new Book(23456, "J.K Rowling", "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire")
    });

    BookShelf bs = new BookShelf(list);
    for(Book b : list)
    {
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    List<Book> list2 = bs.returnListOfBooks();
    for(Book b : list2)
    {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
  }
}
```